# Why is `systemd-tmpfiles --clean` not working?

Tags: systemd, tmp

I have the following configuration to clean up temporary files (default for CentOS 7), which says that files in `/tmp` should be removed if they are more than 10 days old.

```
[root]# tail -n +10 /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf | head -n 3
# Clear tmp directories separately, to make them easier to override
d /tmp 1777 root root 10d
d /var/tmp 1777 root root 30d
```

However, even after running `systemd-tmpfiles --clean`, when I look at the contents of `/tmp`, there are files in there that are more than 10 days old.

```
[root]# ls -dl /tmp/backup-inspection
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 68 Aug 29  2014 /tmp/backup-inspection
```

The contents of the `/tmp` directory is huge:

```
[root]# du -h /tmp | tail -n 1
3.5G    /tmp
```

Can anyone explain to me why the `backup-inspection` directory is not removed? It is nearly 1 year old?

Comment: It probably isn't a `systemd` tmpfile. Not everything in /tmp is, any application can create files in `/tmp`

Comment: I didn't think it mattered who created the file in the `/tmp` directory. E.g., if I write an application that writes to `/tmp`, should the tempfiles daemon delete it regardless of who created it?

Comment: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html

Comment: Quick addition: It does not matter, at least if you use the `e` flag.

Answer (score 14):

I have run into the same problem recently and found this question, so i am sharing my experience.

Actually `systemd-tmpfiles` has full support for recursive directory tree processing as you would expect (the other answer confused me enough to check the source code). The reason files was not deleted (in my case) was `atime`. `systemd-tmpfiles` checks `ctime` (except for directories), `mtime` and `atime` and all three (or two) of them must be old enough for the file (or directory) to be deleted.

Actually there may be other reasons, because `systemd-tmpfiles` has a lot of internal rules for skipping files. To find out why some files are not deleted, run `systemd-tmpfiles` as following:

```
env SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug systemd-tmpfiles --clean
```

It will probably dump a lot of output into your console. Note that if you try to redirect `stdout` to e.g. a file, output disappears and is sent to systemd journal (so that it can be obtained via e.g. `journalctl`). In my case the output was also cut in the middle (or i just do not know how to use `journalctl`), so my solution was to temporarily increase history buffer in my terminal emulator.

Answer (score 10):

I've been going to great lengths lately to solve similar issues on servers under my purview.

The simple answer is basically just: **`systemd-tmpfiles --clean` is a hot mess and you should look into alternatives**

The less simple answer is a bit long.

`systemd-tmpfiles` performs a variety of tasks, but its main one is unrelated to the `--clean` option: ensuring that the state of your system is appropriately 'reset' upon reboots. That is to say, it ensures that directories and files which need to exist for various reasons are created, and ones which should not exist are removed (along with a long list of relatively esoteric things like creating filesystem subvolumes and quotas, block devices, etc., changing permissions, SELinux attributes, etc. See the manpage if you're curious about everything). These tasks are performed by `systemd-tmpfiles --create` (for most things) and `systemd-tmpfiles --remove` (for removing files and directories). These two subcommands consider, roughly, the start of each configuration line: the first field is the type of action, the second the target, the third the mode, etc. Generally, something like `systemd-tmpfiles --create --remove` is run shortly after boot of the system, before anything that might depend on the actions it takes. One important thing to note is that these actions don't ever look at the fifth argument, the Age parameter. That's where `--clean` comes in.

`systemd-tmpfiles --clean` essentially piggybacks on top of this infrastructure by way of a single added field: the Age field. It only considers a few of the particular types of actions the other subcommands do, though: `d, D, v, q, Q, C`, and also `x` and `X` (which only exist to exclude specific things from its cleanup). The ones of these that are relevant to normal use cases are just `d` and `D`, though, used for directories, creating-if-doesn't-exist and creating-if-doesn't-exist-or-emptying-if-it-does, respectively. With the ages marked, `systemd-tmpfiles --clean` will remove the listed path when the age is older than configured.

Here's the catch: it really means **the listed path only** - the age marking is not recursively applied to the contents of the folder. This means that the configuration lines in your question will only ever remove the entirety of `/tmp` or `/var/tmp`, and only if nothing has happened within them for 10 or 30 days, respectively. To make things worse, none of the things which affect the age support globs except for `x` and `X`, which are for *excluding* things from cleanup.

The `tmpfiles.d` manpage does list one interesting thing which may work for your case if you're lucky: "If the age field starts with a tilde character "~", the clean-up is only applied to files and directories one level inside the directory specified, but not the files and directories immediately inside it." -- for my case, the cleanup needed to happen two levels below `/tmp`, so there was no way to use this to good effect.

Look into other solutions for cleaning up the contents of your `/tmp` directory which consider it their primary purpose, rather than being tacked-on the end like `systemd-tmpfiles --clean` is.

Comment: This is an older question now, but I ended up using `tmpwatch` which worked beautifully the first time around. I simply added it to cron's `daily` schedule. Easy to configure, easy to use. Very different to `systemd`, which tries to do too much.

Comment: tmpwatch is quite nice, but it not in the SLES default repos. For me the trick was to give the persmissions when trying to clean up a directory. Not sure if that is by design, the documentation reads otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

- `d` is for creating directories
- `r` is for removing files

From `tempfiles.d(5)`. You don't need the other stuff, try:

```
d /tmp      1d

   d
       Create a directory if it does not exist yet.

   D
       Create or empty a directory.
r
       Remove a file or directory if it exists. This may not be used to
       remove non-empty directories, use R for that. Lines of this type
       accept shell-style globs in place of normal path names. Does not
       follow symlinks.

   R
       Recursively remove a path and all its subdirectories (if it is a
       directory). Lines of this type accept shell-style globs in place
       of normal path names. Does not follow symlinks.
```

Comment: Don't forget to run                                                                                 #systemctl enable systemd-tmpfiles                                                   #systemctl start systemd-tmpfiles                                                   #systemd-tempfiles --clean

Comment: Except the removal of files and directories based on age does not work for the "r" action, but works for "d" (and a few others.)

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this for far longer that it should have taken.

My case was that I have a custom tmp directory (needed for a custom application, placed on a fast-ish SSD disk) that needed cleaned of files that had sat unused for seven days.

What I ended up doing was creating a file in `/etc/tmpfiles.d` called 'foo.conf', with the following line:

```
d /foo/tmp - - - 7d
```

What this does (I hope) is:

1. Delete files and directories under `/foo/tmp` where atime, mtime and ctime are all older than 7 days.
2. Don't delete contents in case of reboot.
3. Create the directory if it doesn't exist (it always will.)
4. Don't change ownership and permissions on the directory (Mode, UID and GID are all set to `-`)

I think it's very confusing that `r` isn't used to remove files due to age. From the man page:

> The age field only applies to lines starting with d, D, e, v, q, Q, C, x and X.